Multi-computer multi-psu configuration
Sorry if the title is unhelpful, I have no idea how to better word it.
I am setting up a NAS, but the SATA power cable that I have can't plug into the motherboard of the old office computer that I'm using. The motherboard has a plug for this power, but the cord I have just doesn't fit (I assume due to no cross compatibility between PSU cables?). But, I have some extra plug-ins on my PC's PSU, so I figured I could just plug the power in there, and it'd be fine. The problem I'm finding is that the PSU for my main PC only provides power to these drives when my main PC is powered on, and I don't want to have to keep my main PC on 24/7.
Any suggestions? I can provide more details or images if needed, I'm just not sure where to even start.
EDIT:
NAS Motherboard info:
HP Prodesk 400 G5 L053359
There is a SATA power port on the motherboard, as can be seen in this image: https://www.ebay.ca/itm/224992557527.
However, it is a different style to the cord I have, as can be seen in this image: (Cord that supports enough SATA drives that I'm using on the left, original cord from the office computer on the right.) 
All drives are tested to be working as long as my main PC is on.
The PSU on my NAS PC is some original proprietary one, it has no extra plug-ins.
The PSU on my main PC is a 1200W Thermaltake Toughpower GF3.

Please, add to your post information about the model and specs of your motherboard and power supply.

@JorgeLuiz Added the info
